# How to use Angular components in paperbits

Tags: angular, web, web-applications, azure-api-management

I am trying to include an Angular component as widget or as component within paperbits. In the documentation it seems that this should be possible https://paperbits.io/wiki/widget-anatomy. But I can not get it run and I also can't find any examples to this topic.
Does anyone have experience with that and can show me a minimalistic example how to use angular components within paperbits?

Answer (score 2):

Right now we have an example for Vue. 
https://github.com/paperbits/paperbits-demo/tree/master/src/components/click-counter

We are working on documentation and examples for React and Angular.
Coming soon.

Comment: I see this is 3 months old, any chance there's an angular example?  I'll check the Vue and React that I see ATM.

Comment: Yes, we did the React example. Angular is the next in our list.

Comment: Please, have a look at this article: https://paperbits.io/wiki/ui-frameworks